What is the correct translation of this Husserl's sentence in first order logic?
I found this Husserl's proposition in a book:

The sum of the angles of a triangle is equal to the color red

I'm not interested in the philosophical issue behind that sentence.
I would just like to know if it has a translation into first order logic.
I tried to translate it and this is the result:
$\forall{x}(T(x)\to{\exists{y}\exists{z}\exists{w}(A(y,x)\land{A(z,x)}\land{A(w,x)}\land{y\neq{z}}\land{y\neq{w}}\land{z\neq{w}}\land{s(y,z,w)={R}})})$
Where:

$T$ denotes the property of "being a triangle"
$A$ denotes the relation of "... is an angle of ..."
$s(y,z,w)$ denotes the sum of the angles which is a number, $s$ a functor
R denotes the set of the objects that have the property of being red.

Since $s(.,.,.)$ denotes a number, in set theory every number can be represented as the set of his predecessors, so in the last part of the formula $(s(.,.,.) = R)$ the equality is between two sets.
I'm wondering whether this analysis is correct?

I don't think so. The way it is right now, there is nothing saying that the three angles are the three different angles. But you can add that in pretty easily.

Thank you @roundsquare for you feedback!

There's nothing in there that reflects that $R$ is a color. I don't know if you consider that that is part of the definition of the constant $R$, or not.

@JonathanZ thank you for your feedback, I have added what R is in my question

You can always just use $P$ :P

@Bram28 maybe you are right :D
I find that sentence interesting because claims that something is equal to a property

@teoobo Yeah. You would typically use ‘red’ as a property, and use a predicate like $R(x)$. Maybe that was Husserl’s point with this ‘sentence’? That there is some kind of weird category mistake going on?  But if we were forced to translate this, I would do the same as you: treat ‘red’ as a value, and as an object of the domain. But as such, I would use a small letter, denoting terms (variables and constants, possibly plugged into functions) rather than a capital letter, which we typically use for sentences/predicates. So I would use $r$, $red$, or $c_{red}$ instead of $R$

Thank you @Bram28 for your feedback. In this case I choose the capital letter because in my books sets are denoted using capital letter, is this wrong?

@teoobo Different books use different conventions for all this, so I wouldn’t worry about it !

The given formula is well-formed and does not violate the syntactic categories. However, whether it might be of some use is doubtful.
The problematic part is the last conjunct (the others refer to geometry):
$\forall x(T(x)\to\exists y\exists z\exists w(A(y,x)\land A(z,x)\land A(w,x)\land y\neq z\land y\neq w\land z\neq w\land\underbrace{s(y,z,w)={R}}_{?}))$
First, there is the question of how $s(y,z,w)$ is assigned a number while the right-hand side remains fixed as $R$: $180^{\circ}$? $\pi$ radians? The cardinality of $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$?
Second, ZFC, the standard theory of sets, has two primitive terms: the notion of a set (denoted by $\{\,.\,\}$), and the relation of being a member of (denoted by $\in$). Hence, once we intend to translate every statement into the language of ZFC, we may arbitrarily form many such equalities (true or false, but well-formed in either case). Hence, setting down an equality between two sets does not warrant a meaningful expression. We might say, as Lewis Carrol's Humpty Dumpty, "when we use a word, it means just what we choose it to mean," alas that would not take us to a sensible end.
Note that Husserl's original statement involves an extensional mathematical expresssion and an intensional non-mathematical expression (the set of the objects that fall under the concept of redness is only an extensional-mode interpretation for the colour red). The discrepancy should suggest that the given formula actually does not correspond to what his statement conveys.
In fact, that is just what Husserl wishes us to see. Edmund Husserl, who was a doctoral student of Leo Königsberger and later, an assistant to Karl Weierstrass, was keen on the foundations of mathematics and logic and gave them a prominent place in his phenomenological investigations. In the given instance, Hussserl wants to highlight that there is an absurdity and the absurdity arises because of the statetment's constitution against the essential nature of the objects and meanings involved, which are not just arbitrary symbols but ideal entities apprehended in specific ways. To complete in Husserl's own words (Formal and Transcendental Logic $\S$90; emphases in the original, bold font mine):

The important supplementation received by our earlier analysis of the
judgment has a decisive significance for the criticism of logical
principles that we were previously considering. This criticism is now
easy to complete. Logic quite obviously does not have in mind such
judgments as we called senseless in respect of content — for
example: The sum of the angles of a triangle is equal to the color
red. Naturally it does not occur to anyone who engages in the theory
of science to think of such a judgment. And yet every declarative
sentence that fulfils only the conditions for unitary purely
grammatical sense (every unity of a sentence that is at all
understandable) is also thinkable as a judgment — a judgment in the
widest sense. If the principles of logic were to relate to judgments
universally, they would not be tenable, certainly not the law of
excluded middle. For all judgments that are "senseless" in respect of
content violate this law.

